# Typescript swears on type of a string when performing arithmetic operations

Tags: typescript

I have `count` variable, he can take `number` and `string` type.
I assigned him a type `count: number | string`.
In one place of mine when, I perform arithmetic operations examplecount * 5`. I get an type error.

```
The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
```

How will it be more correct to fix this error?

After all, I know that the type of `count` is not `any`, His type is `string` and `namber`.

Or all the same, it will be more correct to assign him the type of `any` ?

Comment: `number | string` means it is either a number or a string and TS is telling you that you cannot multiply a string by five. You need to either convert it to a number first, make sure it isn't a string or anything to that affect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TS correctly shows type error as `*` is binary operator which needs to have on the left and the right side `number` type. This is the difference between raw JS, which has weak behavior of this operator, and allows on using `*` also on different types. TS is fixing this behavior in order to remove this class of error, as nobody wants to multiply strings or objects.

We can say TS strongly types `*` operator for only `number` type (`any` also is allowed, but this is fallback to unsafe JS behavior). In order to make TS happy we can do two things:
- transform string to `number` by `parseFloat` or `parseInt`
- do conditional multiplication only for the `number` type

```
// parsing string to number
return (typeof count === 'number' ? count : parseInt(count)) * 2;

// conditional multiplication
return typeof count === 'number' ? count * 2 : count;
```

In both solution we use only `number` for multiplication. Here a link to [TS specification](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#4.19.1) with the behavior

Answer (score 0):

The type of `count` is  `number | string`. That tells the compiler that the value can be a number or string. So while doing arithmetic operations it is throwing an error.

Try this

```
if(parseInt(count)) { // to check if output is not NAN
    parseInt(count) * 5;
}
```

Comment: This will obviously not work if `count` is `0` or `"0"`.